# js add encapsulation to modify property value

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

I have this class:

```
function level(intLevel) {
    this.identifier = 'level';
    this.intLevel = intLevel;
    this.strLocation = 'Unknown';
    displayLocation : function(locationName){
        this.strLocation = locationName;
    };
    this.monsterDelay = 300;
    this.setGrid(50, 24);
    return this;
}
```

and I am trying to add e method to update the strLocation.

I would than call:

displayLocation('location');

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayLocation` method is a function and just one more property. Property can be anything: primitive type, object or function. So you should configure it the same as you did with other properties:

```
this.displayLocation = function(locationName){
    this.strLocation = locationName;
};
```

Another improvement, is that you might want to move reusable method to the function prototype so it's not recreated on every instance instantiation:

```
function level(intLevel) {
    this.identifier = 'level';
    this.intLevel = intLevel;
    this.strLocation = 'Unknown';
    this.monsterDelay = 300;
    this.setGrid(50, 24);
}

level.prototype.displayLocation = function(locationName) {
    this.strLocation = locationName;
};
```

Couple of notes. You don't need to return `this`, as `return this` is implied automatically. It is also recommended to name constructor functions with capital letter, in your case `Level` would look better.